# Функция по поиску букв в строке js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Помогите написать функцию.
Представим что у нас есть строка любой длины с любыми символами(цифры, буквы, ;, !, № и т.д.).
Функция должна определять есть ли в этой строке английские буквы.
s123 - true,
123 - false,
123#$%__s - true,
s - true,
_____________________________________s - true.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?
Или нужно составить массив букв и проверять через него?

Comment: Это хорошо, что нужно. А от нас вы что хотите?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const testes = [
  '12321312',
  '123213f45454',
  'дыофадвыоадлы',
  'дыoфадвыоадлы'
];

function haveEnglish(str) {
  return /[a-z]/i.test(str)
}

testes.forEach(item => console.log(haveEnglish(item)))
```